# How to get the original indexes after sorting a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list as follows.

```
mylist= [0.0, 0.4, 0.81, 1.0, 0.9, 20.7, 0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 20.7]
```

I want to get the indexes of the top 4 elements of the list (i.e `[5, 9, 3, 8]`) and remove the indexes that have a value lesser than or equal to 1 (`<=1`).

Therefore my final output should be `[5, 9]`

My current code is as follows:

```
sorted_mylist = sorted(mylist, reverse = True)[:4]
for ele in sorted_mylist:
    if ele>1:
       print(mylist.index(ele))
```

However, it returns `[5, 5]`, which is incorrect.

Please let me know how I can fix this in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
mylist= [0.0, 0.4, 0.81, 1.0, 0.9, 20.7, 0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 20.7]

indices = [index for index, value in sorted(enumerate(mylist), reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1]) if value > 1][:4]
# [5, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the list along with the index, so that the index is easily retrieved later like:

#### Code:

```
sorted_mylist = sorted(((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(mylist)), reverse=True)
```

#### Test Code:

```
mylist = [0.0, 0.4, 0.81, 1.0, 0.9, 20.7, 0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 20.7]

sorted_mylist = sorted(((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(mylist)), reverse=True)
result = []
for i, (value, index) in enumerate(sorted_mylist):
    if i == 4:
        break
    if value > 1:
        result.append(index)

print(result)
```

#### Results:

```
[9, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

All above answers are good, but if you do not persist to use your current code, and just want to solve your problem itself, here is another option with pandas, just FYI:

```
import pandas as pd
mylist= [0.0, 0.4, 0.81, 1.0, 0.9, 20.7, 0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 20.7]
s = pd.Series(mylist).sort_values(ascending=False)[:4]
s = s[s > 1]
print s.index.tolist()
```